# PowerShell - Struggling with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I'm going nuts with this one, hoping someone can help.  Please be gentle, my coding skills are not great.

I have two separate CSV files I'm trying to do a comparison on.  Each CSV contains a list of computer accounts.  I'd like to export the difference between these two files to a new CSV.  One file is in a defined directory, but the other is found in a separate directory structure. Here's an example:

File 1 in defined directory: `C:\blah\xyz.csv`
File 2 in separate varying directory: `C:\share\uploads\foo\bar\xyz-computers.csv`

The XYZ part of these filenames is a client name and the `\foo\bar\` part of the path could be different for each file.  Every file 2 name always ends in `*-computers.csv`.  I'm attempting to use the search results to do a comparison with the file in the defined directory.  Failing miserably due to my ignorance with coding.  (I'm trying!)

Here is what I have.  Seems to fail due to `$file2` being null:

```
gci C:\share\uploads -include *computers.csv -recurse | foreach {$path = $_.FullName;
$client = $_.Name.Trim("-computers.csv");
$file1 = import-csv -path c:\workingdir\output\$client.csv;
$file2 = import-csv -path $path | Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property Name} | export-csv C:\workingdir\$client.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.  I'm stuck!

Comment: I would start by not putting everything on one line. Separate this line by removing the pipe: `$file2 = import-csv -path $path | Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some sample CSV files, not sure I fixed it or made it worse.  Some of the issues:

1. You piped nothing to `Compare-Object`.
2. Added code to verify that the `Import-CSV` calls worked and write a message if it didn't.
3. The call to `Trim` was failing.  I changed it to replace.
4. The code wasn't very readable.
5. Added some verbose logging.

Remaining issues

1. The export is going to use the last client name.

### Sample Code

```ps1
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\share\uploads -include *computers.csv -recurse
$files | Foreach-Object {
    $path = $_.FullName
    Write-Verbose "Path: $path" -Verbose
    $client = $_.Name.Replace("-computers.csv","")
    Write-Verbose "Client: $client" -Verbose
    $file1 = Import-Csv -path c:\workingdir\output\$client.csv
    $file2 = Import-Csv -path $path 

    if($file1 -and $file2) { 
        Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property Name
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Error processing $path" -Verbose
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\workingdir\$client.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Travis, this works perfectly with one modification:  I piped the end of the compare-object line and added the export-csv command in there.